# Using two interceptors in order

Tags: java, web-config, interceptor

I am using Spring data rest and directly hitting the end point without a controller. As I wanted to validate the authorization, created an interceptor which validates the request based on some claims in the auth token.

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class AuthConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    AuthInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor exampleInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"/api/**"}, requestInterceptor);
    }
}

@Component
public class AuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        //validate authorization 
        if (authorized) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this has been working great. Now I want to add other interceptor so that I can intercept one request and do some process. I am doing because this api doesn't have controller/service so intercepting it is what I thought way to do this

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class ProcessConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    ProcessInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor processInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"/api/entity/*"}, requestInterceptor);
    }
}

@Component
public class ProcessInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        // do some process
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I wanted to invoke auth interceptor first and process interceptor next if request is authorized. And I used @Order to reflect same but it is not working as expected. Is there any other way to do this or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: `@Order` is the usual way to do this. In what exact way is it "not working as expected"? Note the sort direction of Spring ordering.

Comment: You applied `@Order` to configuration beans not to interceptors